# Periodic tasks inside WCF service hosted in IIS

Tags: wcf, timer

We would like to have some periodic actions executed by our WCF service hosted in IIS. What is the best way to do this? Creating a timer doesn't look as a good solution. Creating a windows service that would behave as some kind of a heart beat looks like a problem solution, but it still doesn't smell good. What approach will be a good solution to this problem?

Comment: To clarify this a little bit. It is not a maintenance task, but rather a task that should be executed once per hour to check if it has some subscriptions to terminate, some emails to send and that kind of stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on what your action is trying to do. If it's a database related clean up action, e.g. deleting orphaned shopping carts, you could schedule a job for this in your database of choice, like SQL Server's very reliable job engine. A Windows service would be a great candidate if it's an OS based action like periodic clean up/deletion of files etc. Since an IIS/WCF service is usually designed more to handle external responses I don't think it'd be wrong to use the service layers of the OS or DB for your task.

Answer (score 0):

I used to run into tasks like this in my PHP days, when I would want to schedule an email to be sent at a given time.  After many months of tinkering (mainly trying to handle calls to a page that may never come in), I eventually came to the conclusion that an essentially stateless bit of code is not the place to do it, and scheduled a cron job to fire each night.

I'd definitely recommend going down the route of an externally triggered job (either in SQL, a windows service, etc) and handling your operations from there.  The pain, as I know to my cost, is just not worth the return.

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled much with this, and have, in some cases, where clean-up is required, just done an asynchronous (background) task on the back of a common function to do period clean-up, i.e. On GetCommonList(), I do a check in settings/appsetting for lastrun and then kick it off once a day or every 5 minutes, etc.  That way, if the app goes to greener pastures (which does happen), I don't need to worry about any lingering tasks running somewhere.  Doesn't work in all cases, but security, etc. is also automatically taken care of - whereas services, etc. you may still have issues with that.  Just my 2c.